# Yii Scope with union

Tags: php, yii

I have a current model called `store` when calling the `actionIndex()`

It shows the data in the table as `Select * FROM store`

How would i edit the `Scope` to this? or is there another way to do this, without using Scope?

```
SELECT j.* FROM 
    (
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM `make` AS v
            JOIN `ads` AS a
            ON (v.id=a.make_code)
            GROUP BY v.make
        )
        UNION
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM `store` AS d
            JOIN `make` AS v
            ON (v.id=d.make)
            GROUP BY d.make
        )
    ) AS j GROUP BY j.make
```

i tried this, but get an error

```
public function Scope(){
    return array(
        '_with'=>array(
            'alias' => 'd',
            'select'=>array('j.* 
                            (
                                ( 
                                    SELECT *
                                    FROM `make` AS v
                                    JOIN `ads` AS a
                                    ON (v.id=a.make_code)
                                    GROUP BY v.make
                                )
                                UNION
                                (
                                     SELECT *
                                     FROM `store` AS d
                                     JOIN `make` AS v
                                     ON (v.id=d.make)
                                     GROUP BY d.make
                                )
                            ) AS j'
            ),
            'group'=>'j.make',
        )
    );
}
```

here is the error message

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: 
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'(
    (
        SELECT *' at line 2. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT j.*
            (
                (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM `make` AS v
                    JOIN `ads` AS a
                    ON (v.id=a.make_code)
                    GROUP BY v.make
                )
                UNION
                (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM `store` AS d
                    JOIN `make` AS v
                    ON (v.id=d.make)
                    GROUP BY d.make
                )
            ) AS j FROM `store` d WHERE d.pending!="1" GROUP BY j.make sq
```

Comment: Does this query normaly work?

Comment: @Dinistro yup it does

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have not set your `from`. You could also make an sql view out of the `from` and use this instead. It makes your code cleaner.

```
public function Scope(){
    return array(
        '_with'=>array(
            'alias' => 'd',
            'select'=>array('j.*'); 
            'from'  => '(
                                ( 
                                    SELECT *
                                    FROM `make` AS v
                                    JOIN `ads` AS a
                                    ON (v.id=a.make_code)
                                    GROUP BY v.make
                                )
                                UNION
                                (
                                     SELECT *
                                     FROM `store` AS d
                                     JOIN `make` AS v
                                     ON (v.id=d.make)
                                     GROUP BY d.make
                                )
                            ) AS j',
            'group'=>'j.make',
        )
    );
}
```